# What part of this PHP script is generating the table?

Tags: php, html-table

This is a DokuWiki script/plugin that pulls data from a database of puts it in a table. I would like the text in the table to be preformatted/fixed width. I haven't used PHP or HTML for 8+ years so I'm a little rusty... Can someone help me out?

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * @license    GPL 2 (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html)
 * @author     Christoph Lang <calbity@gmx.de>
 */

// based on http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:tutorial

/**
 *
 * Usage:
 * [[mysql:server:username:password:database|query|refresh]]
 * [[mssql:server:username:password:database|query|refresh]]
 * [[oracle:server:username:password:database|query|refresh]]
 * [[sqlite:unused:unused:unused:path to sqlite3 database|query|refresh]]
 * [[sqlcsv:unused:unused:unused:path to csv file|delimiter|refresh]]
 * [[sqlaccess:unused:unused:password:path to mdb file|query|refresh]]
 * [[postgresql:server:username:password:database|query|refresh]]
 */

/**
 * Disabled, to use that class in standalone mode...
 * // must be run within DokuWiki
 */

if (!defined('DOKU_INC')) die();
if (!defined('DOKU_PLUGIN')) define('DOKU_PLUGIN', DOKU_INC . 'lib/plugins/');
require_once(DOKU_PLUGIN . 'syntax.php');


/**
 * All DokuWiki plugins to extend the parser/rendering mechanism
 * need to inherit from this class
 */
class syntax_plugin_sqlcomp extends DokuWiki_Syntax_Plugin {

    private $sPath = "data/cache/sql/";
    private $sConfig = "lib/plugins/sqlcomp/config.php";

    /*
    Layout
    */
    private $aMessages = array(
                              "error" => "<div id=\"error\" style=\"text-align:center; font-weight: bold; border: 2px solid #0f0;background-color: #f00; padding: 5px; margin: 5px\">%text%</div>\n",
                              "message" => "<div id=\"difference\" style=\"text-align:center; font-weight: bold; border: 2px solid #fd0;background-color: #ffd; padding: 5px; margin: 5px\">%text%</div>\n",
                              "pre" => "<table class=\"inline\">\n",
                              "post" => "</table>\n",
                              "th" => "<th class=\"row%number%\" style=\"%type%\">%text%</th>",
                              "td" => "<td class=\"col%number%\" style=\"%type%\">%text%</td>",
                              "tr" => "<tr class=\"row%number%\" style=\"%type%\">%text%</tr>\n",
                              "same" => "",
                              "new" => "border:2px solid green;",
                              "deleted" => "border:2px solid red;",
                              "changed" => "border:2px solid blue;"
                              );
    /*
    Default Language - German
    */
    private $aString = array(
                            //Number of affected Rows
                            "affected" => "Anzahl geänderter Zeilen",
                            //This Database Type is not yet Supported...
                            "nohandler" => "Dieser Datenbanktyp wird (noch) nicht unterstützt...",
                            //There are some differences in the table!
                            "difference" => "Es wurden Unterschiede in den Tabellen festgestellt!",
                            //Everything is allright.
                            "same" => "Alles in Ordnung.",
                            //The resultset is empty.
                            "empty" => "Das Resultset ist leer.",
                            //An unkown error occured!
                            "problem" => "Es ist ein unbekanntes Problem aufgetreten!",
                            //Cache is displayed, but new data could not be retrieved.
                            "cache" => "Cache wird angezeigt, aber neue Daten konnten nicht abgerufen werden.",
                            //Cache was refreshed, or table was collected for the first time.
                            "first" => "Der Cache wurde soeben erneuert, oder die Tabelle wurde das erste Mal abgerufen.",
                            //New data could not be retrieved.
                            "connection" => "Die neuesten Daten konnten nicht abgerufen werden.",
                            //The data is not valid. Please review your connection settings!
                            "wrong" => "Die eingegebenen Daten sind ungültig! Bitte Überprüfen!"
                            );

    private $defaultRefresh = 1;

    function getInfo() {
        return array(
        'author'  => 'Christoph Lang',
        'email'   => 'calbity@gmx.de',
        'date'    => '2008-07-10',
        'name'    => 'SQLCOMP Plugin',
        'desc'    => 'This plugin let you display reultsets from various databases and show changes.',
        'url'     => 'http://www.google.de'
        );
    }

    public function query($query){
      $temp = null;
      $data = $this->handle($query,"","",$temp);
      return $this->_query($data,"csv");       
    }

    public function __construct(){      
    }

    private function _error($text){
      return str_replace("%text%",$text,$this->aMessages["error"]);      
    }

    private function _message($text){
      return str_replace("%text%",$text,$this->aMessages["message"]);

    }



    private function _sqlaccess($Server,$User,$Pass,$Database,$Query){

        if(!$connection = odbc_connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$Database", "ADODB.Connection", $Pass, "SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC") or false)
          throw new Exception($this->aString["problem"]);

        $rs = odbc_exec($connection,$Query);

        $dbArray = array();
        while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs))
          $dbArray[] = $row;

        odbc_close($connection);
        return $dbArray;

    }
    private function _postgresql($Server,$User,$Pass,$Database,$Query){

        if(!$connection = pg_connect("host=".$Server." dbname=".$Database." user=".$User." password=".$Pass) or false)
          throw new Exception($this->aString["problem"]);

        $rs = pg_exec($Query);
        $dbArray = pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC);

        pg_close($connection);
        return $dbArray;

    }

    private function _mysql($Server,$User,$Pass,$Database,$Query){

        if(!$connection = mysql_connect($Server, $User, $Pass) or false)
          throw new Exception(mysql_error());

        mysql_select_db($Database, $connection);
        $rs = mysql_query($Query);
        $dbArray = array();

        if($rs === true)
          $dbArray[] = array( $this->aString["affected"] => mysql_affected_rows ($connection));
        else
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
            $dbArray[] = $row;


        mysql_close($connection);
        return $dbArray;

    }
    private function _mssql($Server,$User,$Pass,$Database,$Query){

        if(!$dbhandle = mssql_connect($Server, $User, $Pass))
          throw new Exception($this->aString["problem"]);

        mssql_select_db($Database, $dbhandle);

        $rs = mssql_query($Query);

        $dbArray = array();

        if($rs === true)
          $dbArray[] = array( $this->aString["affected"] => mssql_rows_affected ($connection));
        else
          while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($rs))
            $dbArray[] = $row;

        mssql_close($dbhandle);
        return $dbArray;

    }

    private function _oracle($Server,$User,$Pass,$Database,$Query){
          throw new Exception($this->aString["nohandler"]);      
    }

    private function _sqlcsv($Server,$User,$Pass,$Database,$Query){  

        if(!$handle = fopen($Database,"r"))
          throw new Exception($this->aString["nohandler"]);    

        $dbArray = array();
        $keys = fgetcsv ( $handle , 1000, $Query);

        while ($row = fgetcsv ( $handle , 1000, $Query)){
          $temprow = array();
          foreach($row as $key => $value)
            $temprow[$keys[$key]] = $value;

          $dbArray[] = $temprow;

        }

        fclose($handle);
        return $dbArray;

    }

    private function _sqlite($Server,$User,$Pass,$Database,$Query){

        $dbHandle = new PDO('sqlite:'.$Database);    

        $result = $dbHandle->query($Query);
        if(!$result)
          throw new PDOException;
        $dbArray = array();

        if($result->rowCount() > 0)
          $dbArray[] = array( $this->aString["affected"] => $result->rowCount() );
        else
          while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            $dbArray[] = $row;

        return $dbArray;

    }
    private function _debug($data){

        $sResponse = "";
        foreach($data as $key => $value)
            $sResponse .= "".$key . "=> " .$value ."<br/>\n";            
        return $sResponse;

    }

    private function _verifyInput($data){
      if(!is_array($data))
        return false;
      if(count($data) != 7)
        return false;
      return true;    
    }

    private function _load($filename){

        $Cache = null;
        $Update = true;
        if(file_exists($filename)){
          $Cache = file_get_contents($filename);  
          $Cache = unserialize($Cache);

          $Update = $Cache["Update"];
          if(time() > $Update)
            $Update = true;
          else
            $Update = false;
          $Cache = $Cache["Table"];    
        }        

        return array($Update,$Cache);
    }

    private function _save($filename,$rs,$timestamp){
        $timestamp = (time() + ($timestamp*60));
        $Cache["Update"] = $timestamp;
        $Cache["Table"] = $rs;

        $Cache = serialize($Cache);

        $handle = fopen($filename,"w");
        fwrite($handle,$Cache);
        fclose($handle);


    }
    private function array2csv($data){

      $sResponse = "";

      $keys = array_keys($data[0]);
      $sResponse .= implode(";",$keys)."\n";
      foreach($data as $row)
        $sResponse .= implode(";",$row)."\n";


      return $sResponse;

    }


    private function _query($data,$type=null) {      

        //return $this->_debug($data);

        if(!$this->_verifyInput($data))
          return $this->_error($this->aString["wrong"]);

        if(!is_dir($this->sPath))
          mkdir($this->sPath);

        $filename = $this->sPath.md5($data[0].$data[1].$data[2].$data[3].$data[4].$data[5]);

        $Cache = $this->_load($filename);
        $Update = true;
        if(is_array($Cache)){
          $Update = $Cache[0];
          $Cache = $Cache[1];
        }

        try{  
          switch($data[0]){
            case "mysql": $rs = $this->_mysql($data[1], $data[2], $data[3],$data[4],$data[5]); break;
            case "mssql": $rs = $this->_mssql($data[1], $data[2], $data[3],$data[4],$data[5]); break;
            case "oracle": $rs = $this->_oracle($data[1], $data[2], $data[3],$data[4],$data[5]); break;
            case "sqlite": $rs = $this->_sqlite($data[1], $data[2], $data[3],$data[4],$data[5]); break;
            case "sqlaccess": $rs = $this->_sqlaccess($data[1], $data[2], $data[3],$data[4],$data[5]); break;
            case "postgresql": $rs = $this->_postgresql($data[1], $data[2], $data[3],$data[4],$data[5]); break;
            case "sqlcsv": $rs = $this->_sqlcsv($data[1], $data[2], $data[3],$data[4],$data[5]); break;
            default: return $this->_error($this->aString["nohandler"]);
          }
        }catch(Exception $ex){
          $sResponse = $this->_error($this->aString["problem"]);
          if(isset($Cache)){
            $sResponse = $this->_print($Cache);    
            $sResponse .= $this->_error($this->aString["cache"]);
          }
          return $sResponse;
        }    

        if ($rs === false){
          return $this->_error($this->aString["empty"] );
        }

        if(isset($type) && $type == "csv")
          return $this->array2csv($rs);

        $difference = $this->_difference($Cache,$rs);
        $sResponse = $difference[0];    

        if($Update && isset($rs)){
          $this->_save($filename,$rs,$data[6]);      

        }  

        $sResponse .= $difference[1];      


        return $sResponse;
    }
    function _print($array){

        $i = 0;

        $th = "";
        $td = "";
        $tr = "";
        if(!isset($array[0]))
          return $this->_error($this->aString["problem"]);

        $temp = array_keys($array[0]);
        foreach($temp as $column){
          if($column == "type")
            continue;  
          $th .= str_replace(array("%number%","%text%","%type%"),array(0,$column,""),$this->aMessages["th"]);      
        }
        $tr = str_replace(array("%number%","%text%","%type%"),array(0,$th,""),$this->aMessages["tr"]);

        foreach($array as $row) {

          $j = 0;
          $td = "";
          if(!isset($row["type"]))
            $row["type"] = $this->aMessages["same"];

          foreach($row as $key => $Value){          
            if($key == "type")
              continue;  
            $td .= str_replace(array("%number%","%text%","%type%"),array($j,$Value,$row["type"]),$this->aMessages["td"]);
            $j++;            
          }
          $tr .= str_replace(array("%number%","%text%","%type%"),array($i,$td,$row["type"]),$this->aMessages["tr"]);
          $i++;          
        }

        $sResponse = $this->aMessages["pre"];
        $sResponse .= $tr;        
        $sResponse .= $this->aMessages["post"];

        return $sResponse;


    }


    function _difference($Cache,$New){

            if($New == $Cache){
              return array($this->_print($New),"");
              return array($this->_print($New),$this->_message($this->aString["same"]));
            }

            if(!isset($New) && isset($Cache))
              return array($this->_print($Cache),$this->_message($this->aString["difference"]));

            if(isset($New) && !isset($Cache))
              return array($this->_print($New),$this->_message($this->aString["first"]));

            if(count($New) <= 0)
              return array($this->_print($Cache),$this->_message($this->aString["connection"]));

            $Max = count($Cache);
            if(count($New) > count($Cache))
              $Max = count($New);

            $PrintArray = array();        

            for($i=0; $i < $Max; $i++){
              if(isset($Cache[$i]) && !isset($New[$i]))
                $PrintArray[] = array_merge($Cache[$i],array("type" => $this->aMessages["deleted"]));

              if(!isset($Cache[$i]) && isset($New[$i]))
                $PrintArray[] = array_merge($New[$i],array("type" => $this->aMessages["new"]));

              if(isset($Cache[$i]) && isset($New[$i])){
                if($Cache[$i] != $New[$i]){
                  $PrintArray[] = array_merge($Cache[$i],array("type" => $this->aMessages["changed"]));
                  $PrintArray[] = array_merge($New[$i],array("type" => $this->aMessages["changed"]));
                }else
                  $PrintArray[] = array_merge($New[$i],array("type" => $this->aMessages["same"]));

              }                

            }

            return array($this->_print($PrintArray),$this->_message($this->aString["difference"]));

    }

    function connectTo($mode) {
        $this->Lexer->addSpecialPattern('\[\[mysql\:.*?\]\]', $mode, 'plugin_sqlcomp');
        $this->Lexer->addSpecialPattern('\[\[mssql\:.*?\]\]', $mode, 'plugin_sqlcomp');
        $this->Lexer->addSpecialPattern('\[\[oracle\:.*?\]\]', $mode, 'plugin_sqlcomp');
        $this->Lexer->addSpecialPattern('\[\[sqlite\:.*?\]\]', $mode, 'plugin_sqlcomp');
        $this->Lexer->addSpecialPattern('\[\[sqlaccess\:.*?\]\]', $mode, 'plugin_sqlcomp');
        $this->Lexer->addSpecialPattern('\[\[postgresql\:.*?\]\]', $mode, 'plugin_sqlcomp');
        $this->Lexer->addSpecialPattern('\[\[sqlcsv\:.*?\]\]', $mode, 'plugin_sqlcomp');

        if(!file_exists($this->sConfig))
          $this->_createConfig();  

        include($this->sConfig);

        foreach($sqlcomp as $key => $value)
          $this->Lexer->addSpecialPattern('\[\['.$key.'.*?\]\]', $mode, 'plugin_sqlcomp');


    }
    function _createConfig(){  

        $sContent = "";
        $sContent .= "<?php\n";
        $sContent .= "//Sample Configfile\n";
        $sContent .= "//Add as many servers as you want here...\n";
        $sContent .= '$sqlcomp["localhost"] = "mysql:localhost:root::information_schema";';
        $sContent .= '$sqlcomp["sampleconnection"] = "sqltype:servername:username:password:database";';
        $sContent .= "\n?>\n";

        $handle = fopen($this->sConfig,"w");
        fwrite($handle,$sContent);
        fclose($handle);

    }

    function getType() { return 'substition'; }

    function getSort() { return 267; }

    function handle($match, $state, $pos, &$handler) {

        $temp = $match;
        $match = substr($match,2,-2);

        $MyData = array();       
        $match = explode("|",$match);   

        if(file_exists($this->sConfig))
          include($this->sConfig);

        foreach($sqlcomp as $key => $value)
          if($key == $match[0])
            $match[0] = $value;

        $MyData =  explode(":",$match[0]);
        $MyData[] = $match[1];    

        if(isset($match[2]))
          $MyData[] = $match[2];    
        else
          $MyData[] = $this->defaultRefresh;  

        for($i=0;$i < 5; $i++)
          $MyData[$i] = str_replace(" ", ":",$MyData[$i]);

        return $MyData;

    }

    function render($mode, &$renderer, $data) {

        if ($mode == 'xhtml') {          
            $renderer->doc .= $this->_query($data);               
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

OK. It's down to these 3 lines.

```
"th" => "<pre><th class=\"row%number%\" style=\"%type%\">%text%</th></pre>",
"td" => "<pre><td class=\"col%number%\" style=\"%type%\">%text%</td></pre>",
"tr" => "<pre><tr class=\"row%number%\" style=\"%type%\">%text%</tr>\</pre>n",
```

Anyone w/ wiki smarts know how to get that into  style text?

Comment: Lines 44 - 56. Change the styling there, etc.
Specifically lines 49 - 51.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 "td" => "<td class=\"col%number%\" style=\"%type%\"><code>%text%</code></td>",
```

I added the  tags. Viola.